# Time machine stuck on cleaning up/ Error -47

Tags: time-machine

I have been using time machine with the same disk for a year or so and until now it was fine. But since yesterday, it gets stuck at "cleaning up" and if I say "stop backing up" nothing happens. I tried repairing the disk with the disk utility and it seemed to be ok. I also tried a "full reset" (http://pondini.org/TM/A4.html), to no avail. Time machine buddy shows me the following:

```
Starting standard backup
Backing up to: /Volumes/LaCie 1/Backups.backupdb
Event store UUIDs don't match for volume: Macintosh HD
Node requires deep traversal:/ reason:must scan subdirs|new event db|
No pre-backup thinning needed: 71.44 GB requested (including padding), 243.73 GB available
Stopping backup.
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Error: (-47) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/blub/Downloads/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer/Installer Tome 3.MPQE.part to /Volumes/LaCie 1/Backups.backupdb/aliscafo/2012-06-05-010535.inProgress/53345109-BD64-4FAB-990C-772890BF111A/Macintosh HD/Users/blub/Downloads/Diablo-III-8370-enGB-Installer
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Copied 13200 files (12.1 GB) from volume Macintosh HD.
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Copy stage failed with error:11
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Error writing to backup log.  NSFileHandleOperationException:*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Resource busy
Error: (-47) Creating directory aliscafo 2
Error: (-47) Creating directory aliscafo 3
Error: (-47) Creating directory aliscafo 4
Error: (-47) Creating directory aliscafo 5
Error: (-47) Creating directory aliscafo 6
Error: (-47) Creating directory aliscafo 7
```

and so on... Does anyone know what Error: (-47) means? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please: which operating system? What model is the LaCie, and how is it connected?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I got a new iMac, did a transfer from Snow Leopard to Lion and it just go stuck. I did everything but to no avail.

If you are on the same boat as me, I fixed it upgrading to Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

## -47

This almost certainly indicates that the file is busy. More specifically:

```
fBsyErr
```

### Selected references

http://opensource.apple.com/source/diskdev_cmds/diskdev_cmds-557/fsck_hfs.tproj/dfalib/SRuntime.h in Apple open source for OS X 10.8.1

[Archived - Mac OS System Error Codes: 0 to -261](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1618)